# Maven dependency version, use one version or the other

Tags: maven, dependencies

I am building a Dev version of my app that have multiple dependencies.  All dependencies are set up as 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
However, as i build some of the dependencies, the version would be similar to “DEV-SNAPSHOT”. What I need is the ability to pass in that version(DEV)  and have each dependency pull it if that version exist, otherwise pull 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.  Everything I have found gets me both of they both exist-I only want those that have a dev to pull dev and the others to pull 1.0.0.
Is that possible?
If exist version A:
  Pull version A
Else: 
  Pull version B

Comment: You might be able to do something with version ranges: https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html

Comment: Could you describe your use case in more detail? I doubt there is solution to your question, but if we understand your use case better, we might find a solution for the problem behind it.

Comment: When you say "i build some of the dependencies" do you mean to say modules? Do you have a multi-module Maven project and need to manage module versions? Perhaps you can update the question with an example like `"I have A, B, C, .... then I do .... and expect .... to be the result but instead I have ...."` that would help people understand what the problem is.

Comment: App1 has dependency A B  C.   App2 depends on App1, C, D, E.   App3 has dependency on App2, G, E, F.   Current task makes changes to APp2, G, A, and D.   App3 is the end result so it needs all of the changes from the task and all of the regular snapshots from the rest.   What I want is to build App2,G A and D and push them to a dev repo.  Then the build process will look for the dev repo and pull from there of it exists, otherwise from the regular snapshot repo.   That way I get a complete product with my changes and all other dependencies.